# Shortcut of universal app

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating a Xamarin.Forms app and I want to have an option to create a Desktop shortcut (I already implemented on Android).

I have a protocol that I can use to launch my app, so this is not a concern, and I already saved another type of file in the Desktop to test, my only problem is that I can't create a .lnk file.

In my researches I saw a lot of explanations as to how to create a .lnk file programmatically, but all tutorials were related to WindowsForms or PowerShell scripts (as far as I know, UWP doesn't allow executing PS scripts).

So, is there a way of creating Desktop Shortcuts?

---

**Edit after answer**

When I create the shortcut using the Dialog, everything is fine, but when I create it in the app, the shortcut's icon doesn't change to my app's icon, it displays a confirmation when I run it and after I confirm, it displays an error message saying **The target "" of this Internet Shortcut is not valid.**

[image: Shortcut with default icon]

But if I change the file in any way (rename it, copy and paste it or change it's contents), it changes the icon to the correct one and when I confirm the dialog, it opens my app as expected. This proves that nothing is wrong with the file or its contents, but I don't know how to workaround this.

---

**Edit**

```
StorageFile shortcutFile = null;

try
{
    shortcutFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("shortcut.url");
}
catch (Exception) { }

if (shortcutFile == null)
{
    shortcutFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("shortcut.tmp", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(shortcutFile, new string[] { "[InternetShortcut]", "URL=yourapp:///" });

    string newShortcutName = shortcutFile.Path.Substring(0, shortcutFile.Path.Length - 4) + ".url";
    File.Move(shortcutFile.Path, newShortcutName);

    shortcutFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(newShortcutName.SplitWithoutEmpty('\\').Last());
}

FolderPicker savePicker = new FolderPicker
{
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop
};
savePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".url");
StorageFolder folder = await savePicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

if (folder != null)
{
    // Works fine until here, then it throws an exception (Permission Denied)
    await shortcutFile.CopyAsync(folder, shortcutFile.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows 10 alternative to desktop shortcut is a Live Tile, which is basically a live version of an Android icon. You can create a desktop shortuct by dragging the Live Tile to the desktop manually.

If you want a programmatic way and have already a registered URI protocol, you should be able to create a `url` shortcut instead of classic one. Let's see this step by step:

You can create a URL shortuct manually using the dialog:

[image: manual shortcut creation]

Now this will create a `.url` file on your desktop, which behaves as a shortcut. You can see it in the listing of `dir` command:

[image: dir command output]

Now try to rename the file to have a different extension using the `ren` command, for example:

```
ren YourApp.url YourApp.urltext
```

You can now open this file normally in a text editor to see its contents:

```
[{000352A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000012}]
Prop3=19,0
[InternetShortcut]
IDList=
URL=yourapp:///
```

From my testing it seems that the first two rows are unnecessary and the `IDList` property is also redundant. This means you can just do with the following:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=yourapp:///
```

If you rename the file back to have `.url` extension and double-click it, it will launch the app associated with the `yourapp` protocol, which is exactly what you need.

So to do this programmatically, you have to save a `.url` file with the contents we just came up with and save it where the user wants to have the shortcut created.

There is one disadvantage, that you have to keep in mind - UWP apps are sandboxed, so you cannot directly create files on desktop without the user's consent. The best approach I can see now is to use a `FileSavePicker` to let the user choose a folder where she wants to save the shortcut. It is still quite user friendly and it even gives her the flexibility to have the shortcut elsewhere than on the desktop.

### Update

I have found [this SO answer](https://superuser.com/a/898735/113791) with an extremely detailed analysis of this problem. It thoroughly explains why we are hitting these problems - the URL files are interpreted by Internet Explorer and once interpreted, the URL info is stored as NTFS metadata. I would suggest creating the file with a temporary extension first and only *then* rename it to `.url`. I am not at my computer right now, but I will try when I get there :-)

### Update 2

After some playing I have come up with the following and it "partially works on my PC". The shortcut is successfully created and even has the right icon, BUT each time it is opened it shows the "file from different computer" confirmation dialog, which can be turned off only through **Properties**.

```
FileSavePicker savePicker = new FileSavePicker
{
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop
};
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Shortcut", new [] { ".url" });
var saveFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

if (saveFile != null)
{
    await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(
       saveFile, 
       new string[] { "[InternetShortcut]", "URL=yourapp:///" });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I managed to do all that but there's something strange happening. I updated my question.

Comment: That is really very weird... There must be some difference! I will try to investigate this, as it is quite an interesting problem!

Comment: Ok, thank you for your support! :) I already tried several things and none seem to work. I tried to add the other lines of the .url file, I tried to manually create a copy of the same file programmatically after adding the contents (to replicate copy and paste) and nothing. I think its worth noting that when I create a .url file using command line and add the two needed lines to the file (PS>`"[InternetShortcut]" >> shortcut.url; "URL=yourapp:///" >> shortcut.url`), the error is still happening, so it's not related to the code being called from an UWP app.

Comment: Hey! I read the SO post and it's very interesting really, but now I'm trying to do what you said and rename the file after adding the content, but I get `Permission Denied`. I can't rename a file that I just created, this doesn't really make sense I think but... The only way that I found was get Administrator privileges, but that's not an option for me.

Comment: After some hours trying to figure this out I actually created a functioning .url file in the LocalApp folder. The bad news is that every time I try to copy/move it to the selected folder of the FolderPicker, it says **Permission Denied**. But if I try to move other types of file, it works as expected... I'll update the question again with my current code.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the answer again with another attempt which *seems to* work on my PC

Comment: And make sure to try it with a random file name, which you haven't used before due to the weird internals of the .url files

Comment: But there is a big but unfortunately, the file is "blocked" so it displays a confirmation dialog each time.

Comment: It did it!! Finally! The confirmation dialog is not a big deal I think because I can instruct the user to  open the file's properties and uncheck the "File from another computer" box. Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, I spoke too soon... It did work with the first shortcut that I created, but it was luck, now the only way to get a shortcut to work is setting it's name as a single character (e.g. `a.url`).

Comment: This is extremely weird... I have no idea what might be causing this. Even more surprising is that .url causes the access denied when copying when files like exe and dll don't...

Comment: Any success on this? Have you got past the single character file name issue?

Comment: Sorry about it 

Comment: I guess I'll workaround this by saying to the user rename the file after saving it. Probably better than nothing. In any case, thanks for your help again

Answer (score 2):

I have found a much simpler way.

You just need to create a normal shortcut with the target
C:\Windows\explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder{PackageFamilyName}!App

I use the following code to generate the shortcut the first time the application runs (You'll need to add a COM reference to Windows Scripting Host):

```
string shortcutLocation = Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop, shortcutName + ".lnk");
WshShell shell = new();
IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutLocation);

shortcut.IconLocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "icon.ico");
shortcut.Arguments = $"shell:AppsFolder\\{insert your PackageFamilyName}!App";
shortcut.TargetPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir"), "explorer.exe");
shortcut.Save();
```

PackageFamilyName:
Your app family name should be a giant alphanumeric hash, the easiest way to get that is to install it somewhere and use the powershell command Get-AppxPackage https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage?view=windowsserver2019-ps. It can also be obtained in code with Package.Current.Id.FamilyName.

Icon location: This is not necessary it should use the default icon for your app. I changed this because it used a version with an ugly blue background. Adding an icon to your build output folder and linking it as above lets you choose the icon.

It should also be noted that the mouseover text for the shortcut is windows explorer. Please let me know if anyone finds a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to add an ExecutionAlias and create the shortcut directly to the alias.

In Package.appxmanifest

```xml
xmlns:uap5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/5"

<Extensions>
  <uap5:Extension Category="windows.appExecutionAlias" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication" Executable="MyApp\MyApp.exe">
    <uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
      <uap5:ExecutionAlias Alias="MyApp.exe" />
    </uap5:AppExecutionAlias>
  </uap5:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

Then make the shortcut for MyApp.exe

Comment: This does not work properly because although the App starts, it does not start in Store Context and loses all virtualization and Store API call ability.